# Need help differentiating two expressions

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=(x^2+1)(x^3+2)/(x^2+2)(x^3+1)$

and

$g(x)=(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)(1+4x)$

I have tried differentiating them the by using the product rule and the quotient rule, but I could not get the right answer. Is there any clever way to solve them?

Answer (score 7):

Use logarithmic differentiation. For the first one, notice that:
\begin{align*}
\ln f(x) &= \ln(x^2 + 1) + \ln(x^3 + 2) - \ln(x^2 + 2) - \ln(x^3 + 1) \\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} &= \frac{2x}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{3x^2}{x^3 + 2} - \frac{2x}{x^2 + 2} - \frac{3x^2}{x^3 + 1} \\
f'(x) &= \frac{(x^2+1)(x^3+2)}{(x^2+2)(x^3+1)} \cdot \left[ \frac{2x}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{3x^2}{x^3 + 2} - \frac{2x}{x^2 + 2} - \frac{3x^2}{x^3 + 1} \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: That's nice. It's good to be reminded about what logarithmic differentiation is good for, even with such an elementary function. +1 for you. I wouldn't have thought of that.